# How to solve "Operation not permitted" while running i3status?

Tags: linux, debian, docker, i3-window-manager

I'm trying to installing i3status(2.12-1) in a debian docker container(`docker run -it debian`) using these commands:

```
apt update
apt install i3status -y
```

The install succeed and when I'm going to run `i3status`, it shows

> bash: /usr/bin/i3status: Operation not permitted

Calling the full path doesn't work

```
$(which i3status)
```

> bash: /usr/bin/i3status: Operation not permitted

Command `which i3status` shows

> /usr/bin/i3status

And the permission is correct

```
ls -l $(which i3status)
```

> -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 88824 May 11  2018 /usr/bin/i3status

However, when I tried to copy i3status to any other directories, it works

```
cp $(which i3status) $HOME
./i3status
```

The permission is the same

```
ls -l $HOME/i3status
```

> -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 88824 Jul 30 08:37 /root/i3status

After copying back, it works

```
cp $HOME/i3status $(which i3status)
i3status
```

So the question is:

1. Why the operation is not permitted?
2. Does my operation(Copying to other places and copying back as root user) changes anything?
3. Is there any solution to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Running docker with `--cap-add NET_ADMIN` works for me.